# python flask mail.send error check and log it

Tags: python, email, flask

I have Flask app with mail code part like

```
   if app.config['MAIL']:
      mail.send(message)
    else:
      print message.html
```

Sometimes due to mailserver issues, the mail.send() function fails. How do you check for error status
and log the same ?

how do  something like

```
      if app.config['MAIL']:
        retcode=mail.send(message)
      else:
        print message.html
      # now log it
      if (retcode != 0):
         #log it or take anyother action.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to catch exception:

```
if app.config['MAIL']:
    try:
        mail.send(message)
    except SMTPException, e:
        current_app.logger.error(e.message)
else:
    print message.html
```

You can find more exceptions based on `SMTPException`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPException.

If you real need return code you can do something like this:

```
retcode = 0
if app.config['MAIL']:
    try:
        mail.send(message)
    except SMTPAuthenticationError, e:
        retcode = 2
    except SMTPServerDisconnected, e:
        retcode = 3
    except SMTPException, e:
        retcode = 1
else:
    print message.html

if retcode:
    current_app.logger.error(retcode)
```